# Eclipse CDT, build both static lib and shared lib

Tags: build, shared-libraries, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

How is it possible to make project in Eclipse CDT to target both static library and shared library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(assuming you initially created a shared library project)

**Create a new build configuration** for static library (as you do for Debug/Release).

- Right click on project
- Build Configuration
- Manage
- New (follow instruction, e.g. name: Static)
- Properties
- C/C++ Build
- Select the new configuration under "Configuration"
- Build Artifact
- Artifact type: Static Library

**Build your configurations** (e.g. Release, Debug, Static)

- Right click on project
- Build Configuration
- Build
- All

*Release* and *Debug* config should create your shared library 
*Static* should create your static library